# get threejs scene and camera orientation to set default view

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, orientation

I want to create a THREE.JS demo but I am having troubles settings the default camera position/orientation as I want it to be.

I want to set the view/scene/camera manually using a trackball interaction then "reverse engineer" it to set the right camera position/orientation/etc. and whatever needs to be set to set the chosen view as a default.

I played around with the camera quaternion without success.
I would imagine I just have to get the camera position/quaternion from my scene and use it as default settings, right?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

That is correct -- alternatively, you could use "lookAt" and define the camera by a position and a target to view.

If you are using an extra layer of control -- say, a THREE OrbitController -- when defining your view, then you will want to lock the values of the *control,* not the camera.